# System.load for library loading

Tags: android, load, java-native-interface

I loaded a library from the `/system/libs/my_lib.so` directory successfully. How can I use the C/C++ functions which are defined in this library?

```
public class MainFrom extends Activity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainFrom";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        // How to use the functions of test_lib.so? 

        /*
            java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: stringFromC


        String s1 = stringFromC(), s2 = stringFromCpp();

        Log.w(LOG_TAG, stringFromC());   
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, stringFromCpp());  */
    }

    public native String stringFromC();
    public native String stringFromCpp();

    static {
        try { 
            System.load("/system/lib/test_lib.so");
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MainFrom. Success!");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "MainFrom. UnsatisfiedLinkError");
        }
    }

}
```

`stringFromC` and `stringFromCpp` exist in `.c` and `.cpp` files which were compiled to `test_lib.so`

Comment: can you share your Android.mk file and also .c and .cpp ?

Comment: @NISHAnT How to share? I'm building Cyanogen, my test library is in "external" folder, usage of c and cpp functions is in "framesworks" folder.

Comment: @ NISHAnT I can share it in six hours because I cannot to answer my own questions (reputation is less than 100) and there is little place for full code in comments.

Comment: Hi, could you please give me some insight on how to compile test_lib.so into /system/libs/? I have been trying for a week. My post is here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910015/building-system-app-with-prebuilt-so-library, many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

It was necessary to write

```
System.load("/system/lib/libtest_lib.so");
```

instead of

```
System.load("/system/lib/test_lib.so");
```

So strange. If I run

```
adb shell 
ls /system/lib
```

I will see test_lib.so file. Why is it correctlly to load library using **lib** prefix?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to use the lib prefix. If you want to use JNI functions from ANDROID_SOURCES/external/your_lib/, you should call them `Java_com_your_pack_name_YourClass_yourJniMethod` and make a static initialization block containing `System.load("/system/lib/test.so")`

Comment: I know this is old, but can you explain what you said above? I'm trying to include a library from /storage (internal storage)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := $(YOURMODULE_CPPFLAGS)`and in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES := yourfile.cpp` in your Android.mk file to compile .cpp file with android NDK.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Android 7.0, the system prevents apps from dynamically linking against non-NDK libraries, which may cause your app to crash. This change in behavior aims to create a consistent app experience across platform updates and different devices.

[android 7.0 changes description](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk)