# Building System App With Prebuilt .so Library

Tags: android, android-library, android-build

I've been stuck here for a week trying to build a 3rd party .so library along with my app into custom Android system. I followed http://www.maxters.net/2012/05/adding-prebuilt-shared-library-to-android-build-system/ and successfully add the .so lib as prebuilt shared library to Android Build System. Now I can see the .so lib at ../out/target/product/crespo4g/obj/lib/.

But the libraries in this directory are not going to be migrated to device when flashing. And my .so lib is not appeared at /data/data/my_app_name/lib either. So **UnsatisfiedLinkError** occurs when executing **System.loadLibrary()**.

I thought there are three ways to solve this, but just don't know how to implement:

1. Maybe my app failed to indicate to compiler that my .so is along with my app as a whole,  so the .so lib is not compiled into the system image with my app. But I did declare by "LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libXX", anything wrong?
2. Is there a way to build my .so lib into /system/lib/? Where are the so libs under /system/lib/ derived from?

I am new to Android building, please help..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check you makefile against advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687287/adding-prebuilt-apk-with-shared-libraries-to-aosp) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037765/where-to-place-so-file-so-that-it-gets-included-in-the-final-build) as well as the advice in this [groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/4kRyiFofQkA/qvjlVEPwt2QJ)

**UPDATE**
My original makefile was incorrect but this does work for me building ICS:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libmozglue
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmozglue.so
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libplugin-container
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libplugin-container.so
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

where the above are the native libraries required by firefox for android that I include as a system app in my custom system build.

Comment: How was your original makefile incorrect? How did you update the makefile?